# How to get the list of fields from unknown JsonStore objects?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, jsonstore

Writing a function to generate and push some random data inside of the unknown passed data store object. I know I can iterate over records and then iterate over fields, but I need to have the list of fields before starting to push random generated record at top of other records (and then remove the last item to simulate a real-time chart).

Any enlightening idea besides of I am a n00b on ExtJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE:
You are using Extjs 4. Then try this:

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({url:'testUrl', fields:[{name:'value'}]});

//The array of fields(Ext.data.Field)
var fields = store.proxy.reader.getFields();
```

Comment: As I can see "fields" is just a config option and not an instance property. Also I don't know how to get config options from an instance object.

Comment: @user1213299: Which version of Ext are you using?